# Unable to Deserialize Withings Response

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I'm trying deserialize a response from the withings API but it keeps failing.

#### Response

```
"{\"status\":0,\"body\":{\"updatetime\":1494443028,\"measuregrps\":[{\"grpid\":793454575,\"attrib\":0,\"date\":1494373242,\"category\":1,\"measures\":[{\"value\":88,\"type\":9,\"unit\":0},{\"value\":129,\"type\":10,\"unit\":0},{\"value\":49,\"type\":11,\"unit\":0}]}],\"timezone\":\"America\\/Chicago\"}}"
```

#### Restsharp Request

```
var response = client.Execute<WithingsWeighInResponse>(request);
```

#### WithingWeighInResponse

```
  public class WithingsWeighInResponse
  {
    public WithingsBody body { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
  }
```

#### WithingsBody

```
  public class WithingsBody
  {
    public IList<Measuregrp> measuregrps { get; set; }
    public string timezone { get; set; }
    public int updatetime { get; set; }
  }
```

#### Measuregrp

```
  public class Measuregrp
  {
    public int attrib { get; set; }
    public int category { get; set; }
    public int date { get; set; }
    public int grpid { get; set; }
    public IList<WithingsMeasure> measures { get; set; }
  }
```

#### WithingsMeasure

```
  public class WithingsMeasure
  {
    public string ReadingType { get; }
    public double ReadingValue { get; }
    public int type { get; set; }
    public int unit { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: @degant `Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.`

Comment: If it's saying Line 1, Position 1, then probably it's not JSON at all. Are you sure you are getting JSON in reponse? I.e. JSON, not XML, and not "access denied" html page? You can use something like Fiddler to see what you get..

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue of Int overflow for the given dataset. Since, the json is correctly formatted, I would recommend to change the data types of the following properties from int to string and then test the same: -

- updatetime
- date
- grpid

Comment: This doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I have to leave an answer...

Not to state the obvious but be sure not to include the encapsulating quotation marks when actually using the data, Json objects always start with { and end with },
that could cause a line 1, position 1, error message.